# How to evaluate Riemann's Functional Equation

Tags: complex-analysis, number-theory, riemann-zeta

My question is how to evaluate Riemann's functional equation for values $\Re(s)<0$?

I know I must use the functional equation which is defined as 
$\zeta (s)=2^s\pi {}^{s-1}\sin \left(\frac{\pi  s}{2}\right)\Gamma (1-s)\zeta (1-s)$.

Say I wanted to find $\zeta (-3+2i)$. I know how to calculate $2^s\pi {}^{s-1}\sin \left(\frac{\pi  s}{2}\right)\Gamma (1-s)$ at $-3+2i$, more specifically my question is about the $\zeta (1-s)$ term. Would I use the sum formula of the zeta function since $1-(-3+2i)=4-2i$ and thus $\Re(s)>1$?

Thanks for any help received.

Comment: Yes, indeed, you can use $\zeta(s)=\sum_n n^ {-s}$ for all $s\in \mathbb{C}$ with $Re(s)>1$.